# Symfony: loading fixture data with required fields empty?

Tags: php, symfony1, propel

I noticed that propel loads the fixture data into the database, even though we didnt specify some of the required fields of the table inside the .yml files.

What are the reasons behind this? Easier development, etc.?

Schema:

```
  jobeet_job:
    id:           ~
    category_id:  { type: integer, foreignTable: jobeet_category, foreignReference: id, required: true }
    type:         { type: varchar(255) }
    company:      { type: varchar(255), required: true }
    logo:         { type: varchar(255) }
    url:          { type: varchar(255) }
    position:     { type: varchar(255), required: true }
    location:     { type: varchar(255), required: true }
    description:  { type: longvarchar(255), required: true }
    how_to_apply: { type: longvarchar(255), required: true }
    token:        { type: varchar(255), required: true, index: unique }
    is_public:    { type: boolean, required: true, default: 1 }
    is_activated: { type: boolean, required: true, default: 0 }
    email:        { type: varchar(255), required: true }
    expires_at:   { type: timestamp, required: true }
    created_at:   ~
    updated_at:   ~
```

So, expires_at is required: true.

Data:

```
  expired_job:
    category_id:  design
    company:      Extreme sensio
    position:     Web Designer
    location:     Paris, France
    description:  |
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    how_to_apply: |
      Send your resume to fabien.potencier at sensio.com.
    is_public:    true
    is_activated: true
    token:        job_expired
```

So, nowhere is the expires_at field set.

Yet I am able to run

symfony propel:data load  task.

Comment: Can you add your schema ? perhaps you added default values ? are you able to check the table and see what values are present for the "required" fields ?

Comment: Okay, i edited it above.

Answer (score 1):

This link http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp.html explains the defaults for the TIMESTAMP type in MySQL (im assuming your using MySQL).

Answer (score 1):

In another question of yours you quote the save method of the JobeetJob class. You can see there that the `expires_at` gets set there unless set manually before - therefore filling the required field, so all is good.